# Jquery .hover adding a class - Or Child:hover to affect parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have looked around and cant find anything specific to my needs and im having some trouble getting what I thought would be a simple jquery to actually work.

Here is my simple fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/LBHxc/
(apologies as it doesnt seem to be importing the image ive hosted externally.

Html Code...

```
<nav class="nav-buttons">
<ul>
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">Services</a>

    </li>
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">Work</a>

    </li>
    <li class="nav-button top-menu">    <a href="#">Insight</a>

        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#"></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#"></a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-button"><a href="#">Contact</a>

    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Css Code

```
.nav-buttons {
float:left;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 370px;
height: 20px;
}
.nav-buttons a {
padding:0 1px 20px 0;
display:block;
color: #e4e4e4;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration:none;
-webkit-transition: color .06s ease-in;
-moz-transition: color .06s ease-in;
-o-transition: color .06s ease-in;
transition: color .06s ease-in;
}
.nav-button {
position: relative;
padding: 0;
font-size:13px;
font-family: helvetica, sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
margin: 0 10px;
display: block;
float: left;
}
.top-menu:hover .sub-menu {
 display:block;
}
.top-menu a:hover {
background:url(www.anim-house.co.uk/images/drop-down-arrow.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 26px;
}
.sub-menu {
list-style-type: none;
display:none;
position: absolute;
top: 36px;
left:-400px;
width: 600px;
}
.sub-menu a {
width:178px;
height:150px;
background:#3ca3c5;
float:left;
display:block;
padding:11px;
}
.sub-menu a:hover {
background:#3ca3c5;
color:#2b2b2b!important;
}
.menu-drop-down {
background:url(www.anim-house.co.uk/images/drop-down-arrow.png) no-repeat;
background-position: 50% 26px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$('.sub-menu').hover(

function () {
$('.top-menu a').addClass('menu-drop-down');
});
```

What I want to acheive here is when you hover over "insight" you get a dropdown box (3 large buttons) and linking these box's to insight is a little arrow of the same shade blue 
http://www.anim-house.co.uk/images/drop-down-arrow.png <-- that
When you then go hover on sub-menu I want the arrow to remain under insight. 
I have read up into child elements not being able to affect their parents without the use of javascript but I'm struggling to implement. Any help would be appreciated! (And if you could let me know where i have gone wrong.. I am after all on a mission to learn hehe)

Comment: Note that Java and JavaScript are unrelated languages. And if you pass a single function to jQuery's [`.hover()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) that function will be executed both on mouse enter and mouse leave.

Comment: _"apologies as it doesnt seem to be importing the image ive hosted externally"_ - Here's an update to your demo where I've fixed the URL for your image: http://jsfiddle.net/LBHxc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow isnt showing for me so if I understand right when you hover over the parent link you want the arrow to stay underneath?

Ive updated fiddle hows this?

http://jsfiddle.net/LBHxc/9/

```
.nav-buttons li.top-menu:hover > a {
    background: url('http://www.anim-house.co.uk/images/drop-down-arrow.png') no-repeat bottom center; 
}
```

Comment: I only want it to show up on "insight" 
then stay on if you hover over the dropdown insight is the parent of. If that makes sense?

Comment: Ah yes if you check the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LBHxc/9/ it should be working ok

Comment: Solves with css alone, I knew I must have been doing my parents > child research wrong :/

Id read somewhere it could only be done with jquery, but my css structure presumably had the appropriate hierarchy to allow this?
So in theory I was close heh.

Comment: Yea your html markup is fine, you just needed to apply the hover to the li rather than the a tag. And the '> a' is so that the links inside the dropdown do not also get the little arrow applied to them =)

Comment: Just read what W3c has to say on ">" and all makes sense now, many thanks.